# Proper Validation on TPageControl in Delphi

Tags: delphi, validation, tabs, delphi-7

I'm working with Delphi 7 code to ensure that comments are entered on a tab have been saved before users can switch tabs.

The tabs are located on a `TPageControl`, and this code is triggered `OnExit`

```
procedure TfCallerInfo.tsChaplainExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Compare the saved DB value with the text in the comments field }
  if (dmMain.qChaplainCOMMENTS.AsString <> dbmChapComments.Text) then
    begin
      ShowMessage ('Please save the comments before proceeding.');
      pcDetail.ActivePage := tsChaplain;      // Remain on the Current Page
      tsChaplain.SetFocus;
    end;
end;
```

When users click on another tab `tsInfoRequest` for instance, the validation does trigger, but the Active Page becomes `tsInfoRequest` instead of remaining `tsChaplain`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do. Use the `TPageControl.OnPageChanging` event instead.

```
procedure TfCallerInfo.pcDetailPageChanging(Sender: TObject; 
  NewPage: TTabSheet; var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  if pc.ActivePage = tsChaplain then
  begin
    AllowChange := (dmMain.qChaplainCOMMENTS.AsString = dbmChapComments.Text);
    if not AllowChange then
      ShowMessage(...);
  end;
end;
```

By the way, a better test might be

```
AllowChange := not dmMain.gChaplainCOMMENTS.Modified;
```

`TField.Modified` is set to `True` when the content of the field is changed when it's DataSet is in `dsEdit` or `dsInsert` mode, and set to `False` when it's state changes back to `dsBrowse`.

Comment: Thank you @Ken White! :)
I needed to set the `<>` to `=` in the first example you gave, but the concept worked!

And you're right, the better test works perfectly!

Much appreciated,

Comment: Yep, you're right. The `<>` should indeed be `=` for the test you're making. I'll fix it for future readers. Thanks. :-)